# Safe to store password on server

Tags: server

I am making some scripts for personal use. I need to store user and passwords for various stuff. Is it safe to store password text on webserver outside the webroot, eg 
`/var/www/includes/`? Should it be encrypted as well? Or should I encrypt the password and store it in a database?

Comment: Passwords should never be plain text, otherwise you can consider them public and known.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest tu use the file `.htpasswd` to manage passwords:

http://www.htaccesstools.com/articles/htpasswd/

The file contains unencrypted usernames and hashed passwords.

It's one way to protect web ressources from unauthorized access.

[The attached screenshot shows how the login will look like!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9LP2.png)